# How can I check if the uploaded file is pdf....... or image?

Tags: php, file-upload, pdo

```js
 <p class="card-text">
                          
                           <?php echo htmlentities($result2->PostBody);?>
                        </p>
                        <?php 
                        if($result2->URL)
                            { 
                               
                                ?>
                                    <a href=""><?php echo htmlentities($result2->URL);?></a>
                                
                      <?php    } ?>
                    </div>
```

```html
 if(isset($_POST['share'])){
                        $gid=intval(openssl_decrypt($_GET['gid'],"AES-128-ECB", SECRETKEY));
                        $sid=$_SESSION['login'];
                        /*$vimage1=$_FILES["profile"]["name"];
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"],"img/".$_FILES["profile"]["name"]);*/
                        $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pptx" ,"ppt","xlsx","xls");
                        if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel") ||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") ||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])), $allowedExts))
                        {
                             $sql="insert into Posts (PostBody,URL, PostStatus, 
                                    PID, GroupID) values(:cbody,:vimage1, 1, :userid, :group)";
                        }
                        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                        $query -> bindParam(':cbody',$_POST['post'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query->bindParam(':vimage1',$_FILES["file"]["name"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $query-> bindParam(':userid',$sid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $query-> bindParam(':group',$gid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $query -> execute();
                        //$query->debugDumpParams();   
                }
```

I insert post and file successfully to database but the problem with me how I can check the type of the file which uploaded to display it  for example if I upload pdf file I need to display it in href tag while if I upload image I need to display it in image tag

Comment: I'd suggest using `exif_imagetype()` to check for images.

Comment: Does the request include the MIME-type in the `content-type` header? You could use the header value (e.g., `application/pdf` for pdfs, etc.).

Comment: what I need to add to my code please ?